# pause and resume game by one bool

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, resume, pause

I have a strange problem here, I have a bool to control the state of pause or resume of the game. I have a script in a game that has two methods, one for OnMouseDown and the other for Public void ClickToPause which the first one is controlled by a gameobject and the other is used by UI button. problem is, when the state of bool is changed by either of these methods, the other won't affect the bool. like this, if it is false and we used OnMouseDown it changes to true, but it is still false when we use ClickToPause. it got me very very very confused. I need HELP!

```
public class PauseSc : MonoBehaviour {

 public static PauseSc pauseTheGame;
 public bool isPaused = false;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

 }
 public void ClickToPause()
 {
     isPaused=!isPaused;
     Debug.Log("Button pause : "+isPaused);
     Time.timeScale = isPaused ? 0 : 1;
 }
 void OnMouseDown()
 {
     isPaused=!isPaused;
     Debug.Log("Building pause func : "+isPaused);
     Time.timeScale = isPaused ? 0 : 1;
 }
}
```

Comment: Where are `OnMouseDown()` and `ClickToPause()` called?

Comment: OnMouseDown() is called when we touch on the Bank building, and after that a menu pops up, and ClickToPause() is called inside bank menu to go back to game

Comment: Did you debugged it to check if it actually goes into ClickToPause?

Comment: Yes. I have 2 debug.log that shows they work separately